# How to send data from flutter app to DL model running on a VM in GCP?

Tags: json, flutter, google-cloud-platform

I am building a flutter mobile application that requires me to send user given data to a Deep Learning model deployed on VM on Google Cloud Platform. I understand that I must use HTTPS REST API to send the data to the cloud, but I have no idea of how to create the API endpoint that communicates with the VM. Moreover, the model is given data by passing data through commands via terminal. How to ensure that data sent via API in the form of JSON is received via terminal command parameters?

I have tried looking at YouTube videos and going through the Google Cloud website but to no avail.